# Function App key should not change when deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions

Recently we've migrated our Azure function app to Kubernetes. Whenever this pod restarts functionapp key (Default key that gets generated in storage account - Azure-webjob-secrets folder) is getting updated. And we need to change the functionapp key we placed in the keyvault manually. Becuase of this we're facing downtime. This does not happen when we deployed into Azure functionapp. Please provide a solution if anyone ever faced this.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using the latest azure function docker image?

Comment: @Thomas - we are using the below two images :-
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build`
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4.0 AS base`

FYI - image doesn't matter. Every Azure functionapp will have a function key. Because in Azure portal it is one instance, we won't be facing this issue. Where as in kubernetes pods tend to restart and this gives you a new instance/pod for the functionapp. So my function key is changing for each and every restart. Hope this is clear. Thank you.

Comment: You prob need to define a common storage (such a blob) so the keys dont get regenerated => in the same way SaaS function app works ?

Comment: Yes, we are using a common storage account. To answer your question SaaS functionapp works in the same way. We will copy the functionkey from host.json file. But the problem is pod will change every time, so a new folder or new key will be generated.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the function key constant?

Comment: which value for WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE did you put ? I imagine this has to be constant. Also you can only use a storage per function app

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, Azure functionapp is constant. But when migrated the same to kubernetes it won't be a constant. 
`pod 1 :- functionapp-***-***`, after a restart pod 2 will be there and pod 1 will not be in use.
`pod 2 :- functionapp-***-***`
Hope you know about the concept of pods. Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: Could you share part of your manifest please? yeah familiar with k8s.

Comment: `apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
namespace: mynamespace
name: functionapp
labels:
app: functionapp
spec:
replicas: 1
minReadySeconds: 45
selector:
matchLabels:
  app: functionapp
template:
metadata:
  labels:
 app: functionapp
spec:
  nodeSelector:
 "kubernetes.io/os": linux
  containers:
  - name: functionapp
 image: acr.azurecr.io/functions:#{Build.BuildId}#
 ports:
 - containerPort: 3600 `

Comment: Env variables used :- 
`AzureWebJobsStorage
AzureWebJobsDashboard
AzureWebJobsServiceBus`

We're not using `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255357/discussion-between-srinivas-b-and-thomas).